# How to print line and adjacent lines while iterating over a list(2)?

Tags: python

I have a list where each item is a list containing a sentence and a score for each sentence.

```
> my_list=[[0,   'ALL TEXT IS RELEVANT\r \r Good day, everyone, and
> welcome to this Apple Incorporated first quarter fiscal year 2017
> earnings release conference call.'],  [-1, "Today's call is being
> recorded."],  [0,   'At this time for opening remarks and
> introductions, I would like to turn the call over to Nancy Paxton,
> Senior Director of Investor Relations.'],  [-1, "Please go ahead,
> ma'am."],  [-1, 'Thank you.'],  [0, 'Good afternoon and thanks to
> everyone for joining us today.'],  [1,   "Speaking first is Apple CEO
> Tim Cook, and he'll be followed by CFO Luca Maestri."],  [0, 'And
> after that, we will open the call to questions from analysts.'],
> etc...
```

I want to print a sentence only if it has a specific score. At the same time, I also want to print the sentence before and after it.

Something of the nature of:

```
for line in my_list:
    if line[0]==1:
         print(the line before, line, the line after)
```

output: 'Good afternoon and thanks to everyone for joining us today.' Speaking first is Apple CEO Tim Cook, and he'll be followed by CFO Luca Maestri. And after that, we will open the call to questions from analysts.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possible for the first or last items to have a score of 1? What should happen in those cases?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, in the case where the list item is the first or the last, it ignores the edge case:

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if element[0]==1:
        if i>0:
            print(my_list[i-1][1])
        print(my_list[i][1])
        if i<len(my_list)-1:
            print(my_list[i+1][1])
```

If you would like to print them all in-line please use `print(..., end='')` for the first and second print statements

Answer (score 2):

You can zip the list with itself twice offset by 1 each time. This will give you triples, that you can filter by the middle one. It assumes the first and last won't have a flag of 1, since there's not a before or after in those cases:

```
from operator import itemgetter

my_list=[
    [0,   'ALL TEXT IS RELEVANT\r \r Good day, everyone, and welcome to this Apple Incorporated first quarter fiscal year 2017 earnings release conference call.'],  
    [-1, "Today's call is being recorded."],  
    [0,   'At this time for opening remarks and introductions, I would like to turn the call over to Nancy Paxton, Senior Director of Investor Relations.'],
    [-1, "Please go ahead, ma'am."],  
    [-1, 'Thank you.'], 
    [0, 'Good afternoon and thanks to everyone for joining us today.'], 
    [1,   "Speaking first is Apple CEO Tim Cook, and he'll be followed by CFO Luca Maestri."],
    [0, 'And after that, we will open the call to questions from analysts.']
]


choosen = [
    map(itemgetter(1), lists) 
    for lists in zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:]) 
    if lists[1][0] == 1
]

result = ["".join(text) for text in choosen]
```

result is a list of sentences like:

```
["Good afternoon and thanks to everyone for joining us today.Speaking first is Apple CEO Tim Cook, and he'll be followed by CFO Luca Maestri.And after that, we will open the call to questions from analysts."]
```

Comment: Very nice workaround from using the condition I used to avoid the edges of the list! Upvote

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution might be the following:

```
my_list=[[0,   'ALL TEXT IS RELEVANT\r \r Good day, everyone, and welcome to this Apple Incorporated first quarter fiscal year 2017 earnings release conference call.'],
[-1, "Today's call is being recorded."],  [0,   'At this time for opening remarks and introductions, I would like to turn the call over to Nancy Paxton, Senior Director of Investor Relations.'],
[-1, "Please go ahead, ma'am."],  [-1, 'Thank you.'],  [0, 'Good afternoon and thanks to everyone for joining us today.'],
[1,   "Speaking first is Apple CEO Tim Cook, and he'll be followed by CFO Luca Maestri."],
[0, 'And after that, we will open the call to questions from analysts.']]

for idx, elem in enumerate(my_list):
    if elem[0] == 1:
        if (idx - 1) >= 0:
            print(my_list[idx - 1][1])
        print(elem[1])
        if (idx + 1) <= len(my_list) - 1:
            print(my_list[idx + 1][1])
```

Other solution is (it depend what are the uses you need and the size of the original list):

```
ll = list(filter(lambda d: d[0] == 1 , my_list))[0]
idx = my_list.index(ll)
if (idx - 1) >= 0:
    print(my_list[idx - 1][1])
print(ll[1])
if (idx + 1) <= len(my_list) - 1:
    print(my_list[idx + 1][1])
```

2 assumptions were made:

1. If there is no "before" element nothing is printed
2. If there is no "after" element nothing is printed

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use other elements than the iterator is currently on, use an integer to get an indexed element of the array,

```
for i in range(begin, end)
```

instead of sugar coded notation

```
for line in my_list
```

because this way, you won't be able to do it :/

Secondly, you shall have to shorten the loop's length to prevent going out of bounds, that's why the range is 1, length-1. To still print the element that precede, do a test before and after the loop.

A solution would be:

```
if (my_list[i][0] == 1)
    print(my_list[0][1], my_list[1][1])
for i in range(1, length - 1)
    if (my_list[i][0] == 1)
        print(my_list[i-1][1], my_list[i][1], my_list[I+1][1])
if (my_list[length-1][0] == 1 and length != 1)  # avoid double printing
    print(my_list[length][1], my_list[length+1][1])
```

Note that you can put it all in a for-loop, but than you have to be testing for only two edge-cases (start and end), of which you know that are definitely there. So testing inside the for-loop would only make it unnecessary slower.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

```
source = [[0, "0"], [1, "1"], [0, "0"]]

threshold = 0
N = len(source)
for i in range(N):
  record = source[i]
  if record[0] > threshold:
    if i > 0:
      print(source[i-1][1], end="")
    print(source[i][1], end="")
    if i < N - 1:
      print(source[i+1][1], end="")
```

Output for it is 010